# how to get list of csv files modified after 2018 using glob?

Tags: python, glob

I have a remote directory with 10000 files with different extensions. Each file is created all the way from 2015.

I want to get only CSV files modified after 2018.

```
filter = 2018
files = sorted(Path(directory).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)
final = list()
for file in files:
    if datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(directory/file)) >= datetime(filter, 1, 1):
        final.append(re.search('([a-z]+)([0-9]{4}).csv',file).group(0))
```

The above code is inefficient. I am listing all the files then checking for the year of modification, after that I am checking if the file is `csv` or not.

I found the following,

```
from glob import glob
files = glob('*.csv')
```

This only lists `csv` files. The regex pattern match from glob is limiting so I decided to use `re` module after listing `csv` files using `glob`.

Is there any way to filter based on year using glob?

or just the regular ol' loop. i.e,

```
[f for f in files if datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(directory/f)) >= datetime(filter, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Your code isn't inefficient, you will *always* have to check through the files... `glob` isn't avoid that, it's merely hidden from you.  What is the *actual problem you are trying to solve*? AFAIK glob cannot be used to filter by date, it is basically  simple pattern matching for file system names

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am trying cut down the resource wasted since I run it multiple times in my use case (getting list of files from sub-directory). Is it not efficient that I am listing then filtering the files? Shouldn't I request ONLY the CSV files instead of all files then filtering it using re module? same goes for the modification time as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using python3 you can try using os.scandir.
According to the documentation

> Using scandir() instead of listdir() can significantly increase the performance of code that also needs file type or file attribute information

```
import datetime, os
path = "."
cutoff_date = datetime.datetime(2021,9,1).timestamp()
csvfiles = [ f.name for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_file() 
            and f.stat().st_mtime > cutoff_date and f.name.endswith(".csv") ]
```